# Are There Any Tricks to Implement the Sparse Matrix Sum Operation Using SparseLib++?

Tags: c++, matrix, opencl, sparse-matrix

Hi I'm using OpenCL to write a program about matrix and I need to calculate the sparse matrix and its sum in cols and rows separately.

My simple solution is using loop to calculate, but I think while building this sparse matrix, this class will have some member can record this thing.

Do you guys have any experience in using sparselib++? I'm using it and I cant find an API about sum operation.

Thankkkkkkkkks!